# UL element duplicating li element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just a quick question, my un-ordered list is coded to only have one li element, but it duplicates that element and then displays two of them.

example http://stredtech.co.uk/YMD/YMD.php

code behind http://pastebin.com/W9MDTid9

Any help would be great.

I have tried cutting out the CSS properties but it still duplicates.

Comment: Put the code in the question.

Comment: It seems that the jquery.simplyscroll plugin is duplicating your li.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this? It never used to do that!

Comment: Might seem like a silly question, but why are you using a list if there's only one element? Have you tested the same implementation with additional list elements added?

Comment: yes, they all duplicate - I dropped down to one li for simplicity with trying to figure it out!